# SimpleIoC - Type not found in cache: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light, ioc-container

I am running into the below error the first time my ViewModel is being instantiated by the SimpleIoC.  I believe I have setup the container as it should be, but for some reason, I am still getting the below error.  Any ideas or assistance would be very much appreciated.

```
    Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Type not found in cache: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.
  Source=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras
  StackTrace:
       at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.DoGetService(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Users\Public\Downloads\CodePlex\MVVMLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras (NET35)\Ioc\SimpleIoc.cs:line 532
       at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.GetService(Type serviceType) in c:\Users\Public\Downloads\CodePlex\MVVMLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras (NET35)\Ioc\SimpleIoc.cs:line 768
       at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.MakeInstance[TClass]() in c:\Users\Public\Downloads\CodePlex\MVVMLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras (NET35)\Ioc\SimpleIoc.cs:line 708
  InnerException:
```

Here are pieces of my code related to this:

ViewModelLocator.cs (Located in my Win8 project)

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            // Create design time view services and models
            //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            // Create run time view services and models
            //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IParseService, ParseService>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IServiceHandler, ServiceHandler>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ActionViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel MainVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public ActionViewModel ActionVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ActionViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs Constructor

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Variables

    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    private readonly IParseService _parseService;

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IParseService parseService)
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        }
        else
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _parseService = parseService;
            BuildCommonData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was able to figure out what my issue was!  Darn you copy/paste.  My NavigationService implementation had a constructor which passed in the Frame.  This obviously was not taken care of in the container registration.  I simply removed the unneeded construction, and voila, problem solved.  I can share that code if needed.

Comment: You should add the solution, along with the offending code, as an answer, then set it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Add the solution as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is long overdue, but here is the offending code in the implementation of my NavigationService class.

NavigationService class (Before)

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the root frame.
    /// </summary>
    private Frame RootFrame;

    public NavigationService(Frame rootFrame)
    {
        RootFrame = rootFrame;
    }

    public event NavigatingCancelEventHandler Navigating;

    public void Navigate<T>(object parameter = null)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        RootFrame.Navigate(type, parameter);
    }

    public void Navigate(string type, object parameter = null)
    {
        RootFrame.Navigate(Type.GetType(type), parameter);
    }

    public void GoBack()
    {
        if (RootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            RootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }

    public void GoForward()
    {
        if (RootFrame.CanGoForward)
        {
            RootFrame.GoForward();
        }
    }
}
```

I simply took out the constructor, and made the RootFrame private variable a property.  Like so:

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the root frame.
    /// </summary>
    private static Frame RootFrame
    {
        get { return Window.Current.Content as Frame; }
    }

    public event NavigatingCancelEventHandler Navigating;

    public void Navigate<T>(object parameter = null)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        RootFrame.Navigate(type, parameter);
    }

    public void Navigate(string type, object parameter = null)
    {
        RootFrame.Navigate(Type.GetType(type), parameter);
    }

    public void GoBack()
    {
        if (RootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            RootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }

    public void GoForward()
    {
        if (RootFrame.CanGoForward)
        {
            RootFrame.GoForward();
        }
    }
}
```

Simple, I know, but hope it's of some use.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error today in my `Xamarin` project. The actual error given was "**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'**" and then when I look up the `InnerException` I could see the actual error, which is **Type not found in cache**.

[image]

It was a silly mistake that I was using `DataService` instead of `IDataService` for the Constructor Dependency Injection.

```
public SearchViewModel(DataService dataService, IErrorLoggingService errorLoggingService, IDialogService dialogService, IResourceService resourceService, INavigationService navigationService) {
    SearchCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand <SearchFilter>(SearchAsync);
    DataService = dataService;
    ErrorLoggingService = errorLoggingService;
    DialogService = dialogService;
    ResourceService = resourceService;
    NavigationService = navigationService;
    CancelCommand = new RelayCommand(Cancel);
}
```

And just for your information, this is how I registered my service.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
```

So the issue was fixed after changing to `IDataService`. Hope it helps.